# Adding an Appointment to WP7.1 using c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, calendar, appointment

I am attempting to add an appointment to the windows phone 7.1 calendar. It will be a button that when clicked, the button will cause an appointment to be added to the calendar. Does anyone know the basic c# code to do this? I am having trouble finding an answer from Google due to Windows Phone 8 answers dominating the search.

Thank you for looking and your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I understand it's read-only.

Answer (score 0):

We're out of luck. Microsoft states that it is only for WP8 and WP8.1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207038%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Myabe this can help?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202965%28v=vs.105%29.aspx